# Regex match for a specific directory

Tags: regex

I would like to match a pattern which will match all the path starting with `/usr` or `bin/` for example.

I tried the following:

`\b(/usr*|/bin)`

but it does not cover the part after /usr or /bin.

How can I modify the regex to include the rest of the directories?

Comment: Do you want to match `bin` and only `bin`, same for `/usr/` or do you want to match items such as `/binaries/` , `/bin2/` etc?

Comment: What do you want to match in `/test/a/bin/b`?

Comment: Actually I need to specify better. I wanted to match `/bin/another/bla/bla` or `/usr/me/he/foo/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
"(^/usr/.*$)|(^/bin/.*$)"
```

This will anchor the match and will only match directories that start (`^`) with `"/usr/"` and then match anything characters after to the end of the directory string (`$`), and ditto for `"bin"`. It won't therefore match e.g. `/binaries/` if you had that directory on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` in your in your regex will match the `r` in `usr` 0 or more as it is the previous character. Add `.*` to the end to match anything after usr or bin like so.

```
(/usr|/bin).*
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
^(/usr.*|/bin.*)
```

Comment: This will also match a directory starting with e.g. `/binaries` or `/usr1` and all subsequent sub directories.

Comment: that is also what the question states

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified my question. My question was matching `/bin/bla/bla` for example.